# pid for angle on uwsim

Tags: ros, pid, uwsim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I run pid for angle on uwsim. I set ki=kd=0 which means P controller is implemented. There exists sustained oscillation. But after a period of time, the oscillation will decrease and the curve will be paralleled to the desired angle curve and besides, the auv stop rotating. I think the curve should oscillate around the setpoint.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227916/pid-for-angle-on-uwsim/) by [ZYS](https://answers.ros.org/users/25674/zys/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2016-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm not an expert in control but as far as I know a P controller can reach an stable control depending on the model itself. In my opinion this is happening in your case because of three reasons:

- Drag force helps the control making the system more stable with a force that opposes to the movement.
- There are no perturbation forces as underwater currents are not modeled by default. You can add a node to add perturbation forces and publish them on "/g500/external_force" of type wrenchstamped so it is harder to control.
- IMU has some noise that may add some difficulty to control the vehicle, but it is usually too small to have some impact on the system, you can add some more modifying std tag on XML config file for the IMU.

---

Originally posted by [Javier Perez](https://answers.ros.org/users/3430/javier-perez/) with karma: 486 on 2016-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0